# Can i embed the new arrival section from Monday.com inside SharePoint Online using IFrame

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, iframe

I am new to Monday.com platform, But i am working on a SharePoint modern page, and i got a requirement from our customer to show the following info (new arrivals) from Monday.com inside SharePoint modern page:-

[image]

Now inside SharePoint i can embed external iframes using the Embed modern web part. So can we get this iframe from Monday.com?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check the relevant Monday.com documentation or contact their support team for further guidance. As long as you have the appropriate embed code from Monday.com, then there is no reason why you wouldn't be able to use the embed web part within SharePoint Online.

Comment: send them a question 2 days ago,, but did not get any reply till now thanks